# Which player wins in this takeaway game?

Tags: number-sequence, game, game-theory

Two players A and B play a game where they take turns removing 1,4, or 5 coins from a pile of n coins, A moving first. The player who takes the last coin wins. Who wins when: n=18, n=41, n=56?

This problem is easy to solve for small values of n, but for large values I'm having difficulty calculating the tree. Please do not mark this question as a duplicate because the answers to these particular values of n are of interest to me.

Comment: If n=3, do players only have one move (take one coin) or can they take all the remaining coins?

Comment: @Ian Only one coin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Halve or diminish, and race to unity!](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42685/halve-or-diminish-and-race-to-unity)

Comment: @Oray These aren't duplicates. They're similar, but that's generally ok on PSE.

Answer (score 7):

The only thing that matters is

> $n$ $mod$ $8$. If it is $0$ or $2$, $B$ wins, otherwise $A$ wins.
>  This also tells you what is the winning move: you should take as many coins, as it is needed to have $8k$ or $8k+2$ coins left on the table.
>  For $n=18$ and $n=56$, $B$ wins if playing correctly, no matter what $A$ does. For $n=41$, $A$ wins (taking $1$ coin first).

This is because

> from all the numbers giving 1, 3, 4, 5, 6 or 7 modulo 8 you can get to one giving 0 or 2 modulo 8:
>  1-1=0
>  3-1=2
>  4-4=0
>  5-5=0
>  6-4=2
>  7-5=2
>  But whatever you do starting from 0 or 2 modulo 8, you end up with one of the others:
>  0-1=7
>  0-4=4
>  0-5=3
>  2-1=1
>  2-4=6
>  2-5=5

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

> For $n=18$, B wins.
>  For $n=41$, A wins.
>  For $n=56$, B wins.

Actually this question is kinda same question as [Halve or diminish, and race to unity!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42685/halve-or-diminish-and-race-to-unity). The only difference is the methodology. You need to think of this question from the very beginning 2.

For $n=2$, A loses automatically since A can only remove 1 coin and and B will win by default.

Likely, For $n=3$, A win since A can only remove 1 coin and and B will end up with 2 coins, what happens before will happen to B.

For $n=4,5$, A wins.

**Important:** For $n=6$, A has 3 options, to remove 1,4 or 5 coins, if any of these options is lost for B somehow, A wins, otherwise B wins. This is the rule of this game. As a result;

> 1-) A
>
> 2-) B
>
> 3-) A
>
> 4-) A
>
> 5-) A
>
> 6-) A
>
> 7-) A
>
> 8-) B
>
> 9-) A
>
> 10-) B
>
> **11-) A**
>
> **12-) A**
>
> **13-) A**
>
> **14-) A**
>
> **15-) A**
>
> **16-) B**
>
> **17-) A**
>
> **18-) B**
>
> 19-) A

...

> 41-) A

....

> 56-) B

The bold part repeats itself forever. You may find the general formulation on mod 8 accordingly:

If $(n\ mod\ 8) = 0 \ or\ 2$ B wins otherwise A wins.